# My Android app got rejected (Section 4.4)

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I created an app for my Instagram automation company. The only thing the app does is talking to my server, receiving some data and saving data in localstorage.
I submitted  the app on the Play Store 2 days ago. The app got accepted after several hours . The app got removed on the Play Store 13 hours later because it violates Section 4.4

Details:

> After review, XXXXX, com.ionicframework.XXXXX, has been removed from Google Play because it violates our device and network abuse policy and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement. This app won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.

I added some permissions to the app after searching a lot about this horror story. But the app got rejected again. I added these permissions because my app uses Localstorage and InAppBrowser.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I am starting to think the problem is how I store data in the localstorage.
When someone tries to login the app the app makes a request to my server. When logged in successfull the server returns a session key with the account data . The app than stores that data this way:

```
              $window.localStorage.setItem('IBacc', JSON.stringify({username:username,
                                                                minutes:minutes,
                                                                timeNotation:timeNotation,
                                                                account1:account1,
                                                                account2:account2,
                                                                enc:enc}));
```

I am a bit clueless. The Google rejection mails are really vague and I mailed them several times about what exactly is interfering with their policy without any feedback.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: 4.4 Prohibited Actions. You agree that you will not engage in any activity with the Store, including the development or distribution of Products, that interferes with, disrupts, damages or accesses in an unauthorised manner the devices, servers, networks or other properties or services of any third party including, but not limited to, Android users, Google or any mobile network operator. You may not use customer information obtained from the Store to sell or distribute Products outside of the Store.

Comment: "The only thing the app does is talking to my server": what exactly is sent to your server?

Comment: What kind of data you are sending to your server ?? I think that is the problem.

Comment: The only data that is sent to the server are the username and password of what they login with. When they are logged in and trying to access another tab in the app the app sends an request with the encrypted session key to the server. There is also a tab that allows them to enter their username and password of their Instagram account, the app then sends the username and password to my server. The server then talks to the Instagram API

Comment: You are asking instagram credentials.. right? with username and password?

Comment: Yes, I see several apps doing that, than can't be the problem right?

Comment: @Raoul I guess there you have it, you can't just save and send 3rd party credentials to your server.. lol

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @xander That can't be the issue. I see a ton of apps asking for Instagram credentials.

Comment: @Raoul are you sure these other apps are asking for the credentials, maybe they are just using an OAuth token for login and get that from an certified instagram login or whatever (so the app has no access to the username and password itself!).

Comment: @Xander I am 100% sure they don't use Oauth. If they would use Oauth they wouldn't have to give their username and password in a custom login field but they would get redirected to an "Authorized" page on Instagram, (Search Oauth Instagram on Google images, I can post links yet)

Comment: I included a privacy policy on the app page in the Play Store. I will keep you updated on the situation